# Plot Ranged horizontal bar graph with holes using ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I already have a graph using chartJS as shown below[image] and the code for that is :

```
r_chart_data = [[-0.001, 2.052],[-2.385, 2.052]];
dr_chart_data = [[-0.01, 1.83],[1.05, 2.83],[1.05, 2.83]];
myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: label,
    datasets: [{
      label : 'DataSet1',
      data: r_chart_data,
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
    },
    {
      label : 'DataSet2',
      data: dr_chart_data,
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
    }
    ]
  },
  options: {
  lineAtIndex : level,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: -5, 
          max: 5, 
          stepSize: 0.5,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

But what if my

```
r_chart_data[0] i.e. [-0.001,2.052]
```

is not a continuos range and instead its value is something like

```
[[-0.001,1.023],[1.5,2.052]]
```

then how should I plot the graph. Modified r_chart_data:

```
r_chart_data = [[[-0.001,1.023],[1.5,2.052]],[-2.385, 2.052]];
```

Similarly if I have a range of data sets that I need to plot in the form of a horizontal bar graph using ChartJS. The data set which are in the form of:

```
dataset1: [[-10,-4],[-2,2],[4,6]] // should be plotted in a single bar graph
dataset2: [[-2,1],[1.5,3.5],[5.2,8.9]] //should be plotted in a second bar
dataset3: [[2,4],[5,7]] //third bar
.. and so on
```

Moreover, each dataset need not have three range items. It can have one, two or any number of range items.

Comment: @timclutton - The example that you pointed out is not what I want. Going by your example what if the month January had a dataset say [-50,-10] and [15,23] for Dataset1 and [-23,-10] and [12,35] for Dataset2. So how do you plot that using chartJS. Moreover, I didn't find any documentation in chartJS website regarding plotting range data with holes as I said

Comment: @timclutton I have added my existing code and graph and a sample data for which I need to plot the graph.

Comment: Excellent editing. +1 and retracting close vote.

Comment: Hey, I solved this using the stacked floating horizontal bar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60975765/stacked-floating-horizontal-bar-using-chartjs/60976218